# MS SQL Failover Cluster IP address not working

Tags: sql-server

I have failover clustering for 2 nodes with MS SQL on Windows 2016 Data Center

Cluster Manager Name: MPS-CLUSTER
Cluster Manager IP Address: 11.11.11.150
First Node Name: MPSDB01
IP Address: 10.10.10.168
Second Node Name: MPSDB01
IP Address: 10.10.10.170

All ports are configured correctly and I tried to close the firewall but no result

My issue that when I try to ping the Cluster name, if the first node is up then the ping session reply with 10.10.10.168, and if the second node is up then the ping session reply with 10.10.10.170 but it should to reply with the cluster IP Address 11.11.11.150

What's the missing point?

Comment: If you open the Failover Cluster Manager tool and run the Validate Cluster wizard, does it report any error?

Comment: Let's try to take a step back from ping, and see what the DNS resolution is. If you do `nslookup MPS-Cluster`, do you get 11.11.11.150 as an answer?